# Multiple default values specified for column "id" of table in Django 2.1.1

Tags: django, django-models

So I keep getting this error saying that there's multiple specified ID values for the device table, but I don't have a clue where I've specified any kind of default ID.  I've tried setting a field as primary_key=True but that didn't solve the problem either.

EDIT:  [Traceback](https://pastebin.com/0y7axzPE)

```
class Campus(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
address = models.CharField(max_length=40)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Campuses"



class Teacher(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=11)
department = models.CharField(max_length=20)
campus = models.OneToOneField(Campus, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="Not Assigned")
#devices = self.Device.objects.all()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name



class Device(models.Model):
inUse = 'IU'
inStock = 'IS'
inMaintenance = 'IM'
damaged = 'DM'
statusChoices = (
    (inUse, 'In Use'),
    (inStock, 'In Stock'),
    (inMaintenance, 'In Maintenance'),
    (damaged, 'Damaged'),
)

name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
brand = models.CharField(max_length=20)
status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=statusChoices, default=inStock)
#user = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: Trace back? Which model?

Comment: The Device model.  I connected to the PostgreSQL database and can see there is no default id being generated for the Device table, I'm not sure why however as Django should be autocreating the IDs.

edit:  [Traceback](https://pastebin.com/0y7axzPE)

Answer (score -1):

After navigating to my PostgreSQL instance I deleted all Django-related data and remade migrations and things are in working order again.

For future users:  I recommend deleting your past migrations table in your database.